# What is the difference between "krom" and "escepte"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I just read this sentence:

> *... estis nenio sur ĝi escepte de malgranda ora ŝlosilo ...*

It's obvious what "escepte de" means, but I previously learned the word "krom" for "except".

So can the sentence also be:

> *... estis nenio sur ĝi krom malgranda ora ŝlosilo ...*

Is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your two sentences mean the same thing. However, *krom* means "besides", and as a result there are situations in which it could mean both "except" and "as well as".

> *Mi havas, krom la ŝlosilo, ĉion bezonatan.*
>
> I have, besides the key, everything I need.

Do you have the key or not? To distinguish the two, we can say:

> NO: *Mi havas, escepte de la ŝlosilo, ĉion bezonatan.*
>
> YES: *Mi havas, krom la ŝlosilo, ankaŭ ĉion bezonatan.*
>
> or better: *Mi havas, (kune) kun la ŝlosilo, ĉion bezonatan.*

In case you are wondering, *krom* is only followed by the accusative if there is ambiguity otherwise.

Comment: I can add that ambiguity that could be solved by adding an -N practically never appears with "krom". I at least have never been able to imagine such an example. That's why "krom ...N" is normally not used.

Comment: If the word with _krom_ is a direct object, the word takes the N-ending in the usual manner. An example from PMEG: _Krom Vilhelmon Petro batis ankaŭ Paŭlon_ vs. _Krom Vilhelmo ankaŭ Petro batis Paŭlon_. Thus _Mi havas krom la ŝlosilon ankaŭ ĉion bezonatan_.